# An unknown N1QL error occured. This is usually related to an out-of-memory condition

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I  use node js and get an time out exception updating a record in couchbase.Can you help me?

Exception:
An unknown N1QL error occured. This is usually related to an out-of-memory condition.
stack:"Error: An unknown N1QL error occured. This is usually related to an out-of-memory condition.\n    at c:...\node_modules\couchbase\lib\bucket.js:715:15"

Query :

```
  let query = N1qlQuery.fromString("UPDATE " + super.TableName + " USE KEYS($1)  SET Username = $2");
   app.buckets.user.query(query, [documentId, username], function (error, rows, meta) {
            if (error) {
                callback(error, null);
                return;
            }
            else {
                callback(null, meta);
            }
        });
```

My document record:

```
{
  "DocumentId": "39e970c8-fe09-4a3c-88b0-775e1b142ee3",
  "Email": "kaasdfsafz@msn.com",
  "Firstname": "Abdulkadir",
  "Lastname": "Test",
  "Fullname": "Abdulkadir Test",
  "PhotoPath": "kadiroTest.jpeg",
  "Facebook": "10155939238827",
  "IsActive": true,
  "Type": "user",
  "CreatedAt": 1511284826819
}
```

Couchbase version : 
Community Edition 5.0.0 build 3519

Node Js version:
V8.9.1

Couchbase Nodejs sdk version:
2.4.2

Comment: Can you confirm whether this query works correctly using CBQ or performing the query directly from the WebUI?  The "An unknown N1QL error occured" error indicates that the client did not receive any error message from the server (the connection dropped without reason).  Typically we see this when the Node.js application runs low on memory, or when network issues exist between the application and server.

Comment: I do not have any problems when I run the query from the WebUI.
Have I forgotten to open a port?  My server is 4 cores and 16 GB ram . my client (node js , my computer) is  4 core and 8 GB ram. whenever  i  request node js i recieve an exception

Comment: I have same problem here.. I'm found that if you use one node, that would be ok, after i use 2node or above, it will occur same error message. no idea for now.. so confuse

Comment: i found it.this exception is a network-related error. dont forget all ports. `#tcp:4369; tcp:8091; tcp:8092; tcp:8093; tcp:8094; tcp:9100-9105; tcp:9998; tcp:9999; tcp:11207; tcp:11209; tcp:11210; tcp:11211; tcp:11214; tcp:11215; tcp:18091; tcp:18092; tcp:18093; tcp:21100-21199;`

Comment: Same error here, I feel If N1QL query execution time is more then we'll get this error. I ran N1QL query on couchbase WebUI, it took about 4sec to execute, and now my API is failing with the error cause ottomon is not able to handle such N1QL queries.